# Error in getting Android device ID

Tags: android

I am trying to retrieve the device ID of my adroid device in my android app. However, error exists and the program cannot launch after I added the following line in my program:

```
String ts = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE; 
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(ts);
```

From the logcat, it says problems come fromt the second line:

```
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{android.reader/android.reader.Reader}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at android.reader.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:51)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
07-18 11:28:47.453: E/AndroidRuntime(5528):     ... 11 more
```

I think it is caused by the permission problem, but I have already added the following line in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

So, may I ask how can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
androidId = "" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long)tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
String deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();
```

i guess these Answer can help you.[Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: ya, I have read this page before, actually, my method is the same as the one you mentioned. I know I can get the device ID by getDeviceID() method, however, current problem is after I add the line: TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(ts); then those errors exist, that is why I want to ask for help, since I have already give permission to my program

Comment: it doesn't matter now, I have changed my design, anyway, thank you for helping me.